# MS Release Management upgrade from 3 to 4

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, ms-release-management

I am using Release Management Update 3 with TFS 2013.

I would like to upgrade to Release Management Update 4.

Questions

1. Do i need to uninstall and install new set up of RM update 4?
2. I have my release templates and other settings in my current version. How this upgrade going to impact on those things?
3. Any other challenges ?

Please share your thoughts/comments.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you have to uninstall the client and server prior to installing Update 4. It doesn't touch the database until you do the server configuration. It's just like TFS in that regard. None of your existing release templates will be impacted.

Update 4 adds very little in the way of new features for "classic" agent-based deployers; most of the new features are focused in the vNext release templates using DSC.